# IIS: one server - multiple ips - multiple domains => multiple ssl possible?

Tags: iis, ssl

I'm using Windows 2008 R2 and I'm going to host some applications for customers.
I plan to bind different IP adresses to different sites.
The question I have is if I can use different SSL certificates in this scenario.

Following should be possiible

IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.01 => https://www.customer1.com

IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.02 => https://www.abcd.com

Is this possible with standard SSL certificats? What precautions do I have to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfectly reasonable setup, and you shouldn't have to take any additional precautions or measure over and above the usual when working with SSL certificates.

In IIS Manager, you should be able to import your certificates into the `Server Certificates` section. Then, you should be able to define each virtual host as a separate site, and then bind each site to the relevent IP address that it should be accessible over. When you select a binding of type `https`, there's an extra bit labelled `SSL Certificate`.

[image]

The dropdown should list all the certificates you have available. In my case, I've only got a  self-signed, but this site will now serve that cert to HTTPS requests on port 443 to `10.13.111.23`.